# How to fetch logs from diffrent servers using one command?

Tags: ssh

How to fetch logs from diffrent servers using one command?

For example, suppose I want to fetch logs for same id in different servers. 
I have to go to each server and search for logs.

Is there any way to do it one go?

Comment: What logs? What ID?

Comment: Why do you need to do it in a single command? Isn't `scp foo:/var/log/messages . && scp bar:/var/log/messages .` enough?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a for loop in bash.

```
for SERVER in foo bar
do
mkdir -p $SERVER
scp $SERVER:/var/log/messages $SERVER/
done
```

Replace foo and bar with the names of your servers.